# How to store and validate data between state transitions?

Tags: architecture, state, finite-state-machine, transition

I'm developing a largeish application that will have custom finite state machines. That is, the admin users of the application will be able to create their own state machines, limited by little pieces of code that are pré built, lets call those tasks.

OK that is all fine and we are reaching a place where we think its going to work.

The big question is, depending on the tasks involved, we will need to force user to input a certain data.

For example, there is a certain fsm that will merge parcels. For that to happen, we need at least two input parcels and some data on the new resulting parcel.

How can we:

1. Store the data we need, which will be different, depending on the fsm and the tasks it will perform? I was thinking a big json blob.
2. Validate it, without going insane.

Background: Django, marionette js, Django rest Framework and PostgreSQL.

Async tasks and state changes with celery.

I'm asking this because I dont want to have many many fixed models tied up to a certain validation. That will eventually lead to a high number of tables and it will be harder to maintain. (And that why i suggested a json Field for storing all the data for each state, validate it, and if its all good, transition to the next state).

PS: Sorry for bad formatting. Using my phone without proper keyboard.

Comment: Are you building a [rules engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine)?

Comment: Hey snowman. I never heard of that term before. Its something like that, but the tasks we execute are fixed. The validations are fixed by task. What is not fixed, are the States and the transitions they follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go one of two ways depending on the exact implementation details.

(Apologies, I'm not familiar with Django, so my answer speaks generically about the architecture and doesn't have specific suggestions for the language you're using)

**1. JSON fields for data using Single Table Inheritance**

As you suggested, I'd put the data in JSON(B) fields in Postgres. I'd validate by subclassing (or similar) the Tasks model using Single Table Inheritance (STI).

A quick google suggests that Django might not do STI natively, but you could get a simple enough version working by adding, say, a `type` column to your tasks table and use that to dynamically load the class that contains your validations for that type of task.

Pros

- Expressive - your validation rules are as flexible as the language
- Simple - Easy to get up and running with

Cons

- Awkward to scale - If you have lots of different types of tasks, this could get out of hand for maintenance.
  (This can be mitigated by grouping similar tasks to use the same validation class)
- Developer dependent - any changes to validation or adding new tasks requires a developer

**2. Store validation also in JSON**

Have a second table storing your task types that uses JSON schema to describe the attributes and validation of a task

Pros

- Standard Tools - If you use JSON schema there'd be standard libraries you could work with to validate the tasks
- Easier to Scale - Just add a new kind of task to your task type table

Cons

- May be a bit slower - A little bit more involved to develop initially
- Less Expressive - JSON schema is not a programming language, so it's not as expressive for defining rules (but in practice it would be good enough for most cases)

Comment: Hey ChristopherJ! Since part of the code is fixed and new operations depend on developers anyways, we ended up defining a validation schema inside each task. That means that each task expects a fixed set of attributes and validates that before going on. If we have new tasks, it's ok, they just need to define their own validation schema. The user can mix/match data in FSM, but to transition to particular state, each task is the one driving the necessary input data/validation

Answer (score -1):

**Let's understand your context:**

> users of the application will be able to create their own state machines, limited by little pieces of code that are pré built, lets call those tasks.
>
> depending on the tasks involved, we will need to force user to input a certain data.
>
> **Background:** Django, marionette js, Django rest Framework and PostgreSQL.

**Now, your questions:**

> **How can we:** Store the data we need, which will be different, depending on the fsm and the tasks it will perform? I was thinking a big json blob.

You could either:

- Create N x N table in postgree (or any other relation DB you're using) specifying relationships between the pre-built parts you mentioned and each custom FSM; you could create a Field table, which would contain input entered by the user, and the field could have a reference to the pre-built task present in the user's FSM;
- For well-structure data, unlikely to change overtime (such as users/roles/permissions in your app), you keep using relation DB. For data with dynamic structure, or in cases when each instance might have a different format, you could store these info in an additional non-relational or NoSql DB (eg: [mongoDB](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html), which internally uses Bson format). The implementation for this will be very easy and it seamlessly integrates with python (I've used pymongo for it)

**About the comments:** *Whether to use a DB or not is completely orthogonal to the question the OP asked*

There are applications using multiple types of DB, depending on the features it needs. There are apps that use relational DB (eg: SQL server), no-sql DB (eg: mongoDB) and also in-memory DB (eg: Redis). Trello, for instance, uses mongo and redis. Since this post is tagged with "architecture" I think is worth mentioning these options, since it might be useful to help solving the OP problem.

> **How can we:** Validate it, without going insane.

Since you have pre-built parts on this feature, you would need to create **pre-built validators** for the possible input information entered by the user.

If you implement some Field entity, for instance, with a "Type" property on it, you can then implement validators for this type of field; when the user fills this info and choose the "numeric" type the app triggers the appropriate validators.

If you provide more details about the states and input entered, perhaps I can provide some code examples.

Comment: -1 Whether to use a DB or not is completely orthogonal to the question the OP asked. In some situations, persisting the data in a DB might be the best approach, and in others, it could greatly increase the complexity of the project for no real gain. And this answer does not touch on which patterns to use for validation logic at all.

Comment: @Kevin - Thanks for your feedback. Updated my answer. If you still thinks it's useless, just keep your downvote :)